# How to make inputed text vise versa in python?

Tags: python

I try write program that build new word from inputed, where letter is vise versa

```
#    vise    versa    
print    ("word vise versa")
word = input("Input your text ")
new_word = ""
while word:
    position = len(word) - 1
    for letter in word:
    new_word += letter[position]
    position -= 1
print(new_word)
```

Always have mistake

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "4_2.py", line 9, in <module>
      new_word += letter[position]
 IndexError: string index out of range
```

what I do wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `word[position]` rather than `letter[position]`? Also, note that this appears to just be `new_word = word[::-1]`.

Comment: one more, How you will break your `while` loop ??

Comment: Thanks! really "word".... Loop ended by break

Comment: You can use `slice` method also, check my solution.

Comment: men, I started learn python (Dawson "programming in pythopn) day before yesterday, so, I don't know yet your professional methods

Comment: @luckyander don't assume all other users identify as men...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is probably what you are doing in the below lines

```
for letter in word:
    new_word += letter[position]
```

where letter will be each letter within the word, first 'a' then 'b' then 'c' if word was `abc`. On the seconds string you are trying to use the letter 'a' as an array, which is no good. You probably want to offset into the word array instead?

Answer (score 0):

First in your code, if your input is not None or a False Value, your loop will go forever because word is not a False Value.

Second, you can use reverse slice of a string or a list like this:

```
#    vise    versa    
print("word vise versa")
word = raw_input("Input your text ")
new_word = ""
if word:
  new_word = word[::-1]
print(new_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get Input word from user by using `raw_input` method
2. Get length of input word by `len` method.
3. Use `while` loop to add character in new variable.
4. decrement length variable by `1`

   ```
   print "Program: word vise versa"
   word = raw_input("Input your text:")
   new_word = ""
   wdlen = len(word)
   while wdlen:
       new_word += word[wdlen-1]
       wdlen -= 1

   print new_word
   ```

Output:

```
$ python test.py 
Program: word vise versa
Input your text:abcdef
fedcba
```

---

use `slice` .

more info https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices

```
>>> a = "12345"
>>> a[::-1]
'54321'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your code as a a oneliner like this:

```
new_word = "".join(reversed(input("Input your text ")))
```

The `reversed` function takes a sequence type, and returns a new one with the elements in reverse order. However, this will now be a list. 
The `"".join` then joins them back into a string - some join string must be provided, so any empty string is used.

With fewer lines, and no temporary variables, there are fewer places for this code to break.